# problems with ordering dates in r

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to order dates in R. I have some strings which look like this

```
jnk <- c("2016-01-12T10:54:41Z", "2016-01-12T12:40:30Z", "2016-01-12T14:59:22Z", 
         "2016-01-12T15:55:10Z", "2015-03-29T02:56:42Z", "2015-03-29T02:40:56Z")
```

So I format them with `strptime`

```
jnk2 <- strptime(jnk,  "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

When I now try to order them, the two 2015 dates will always be at the end...

```
order(jnk2)
```

> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

Am I missing something? I would expect the order to be `6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: I don't know why, but the 2015 strings don't have CET as timezone. Might be worth investigating?

Comment: Run `strptime(c("2015-03-29 01:30:00", "2015-03-29 02:00:00", "2015-03-29 02:30:00", "2015-03-29 03:00:00"),  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` e.g. with a German locale and you should be able to guess why the values in the middle have no timezone.

Comment: In case I am not able... Does this mean I am stupid?! I really don't get it even with German locale :-)

Comment: Look at the timezones and think what happens on a clock when we switch to CEST.

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce. Everything seems fine.

Comment: @nicola which tells us that you are not in our corner of Europe.

Comment: I'm in Italy. Which are the areas affected?

Comment: @nicola Everyone with a locale where the switch to DST happend on "2015-03-29 02:00:00" is affected. So, you use a different locale or this is platform dependent.

Comment: I am, and I'm not affected. The dates I'm getting shouldn't exist at all (after 2015-03-29 01:59:59 should be 2015-03-29 03:00:00) and still I'm getting `"2015-03-29 02:56:42 CEST"` from the OP's line. However, if I try `as.POSIXct` instead of `strptime`, that date is translated into `"2015-03-29 01:56:42 CET"`, which makes sense. Some mistery here.

Comment: @nicola What's your OS and R version? I believe this used to give NA values.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 and R-3.2.2

Comment: @nicola Yes, this seems to be platform specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue until I defined a time zone (e.g. `tz="GMT"`):

```
jnk <- c("2016-01-12T10:54:41Z", "2016-01-12T12:40:30Z", "2016-01-12T14:59:22Z", 
         "2016-01-12T15:55:10Z", "2015-03-29T02:56:42Z", "2015-03-29T02:40:56Z")

jnk2 <- strptime(jnk,  "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz="GMT")
order(jnk2)
```

> [1] 6 5 1 2 3 4

Comment: Nice, but do you have an idea why this happens?! Couldn't see a difference compared to the other strings...

Comment: Not sure, but for some reason the last two times do not have an associated  `tz` following `strptime`.

Comment: @drmariod I investigated superficially. `order` is not a generic and it calls the generic `xtfrm` and in turn `xtfrm.POSIXlt`. It seems that the latter function simpy converts the argument by `as.double(x)`. Hence, we effectively end up with the call `order(as.double(jnk2))` which gives the wrong order. Why that function just converts i have no idea of.